# How to remove or blog prefix in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, security, blogs

I've run my WordPress website for a long time, and recently got hacked. I cleaned everything I could find and started new.

In Wordfence logs I found that someone tried to log in from blog.mywebsite.pl. I figured out that is from my webp. I realized that "blog." prefix is created automatically after wp installation. This "blog." prefix runs as http, so I could get hacked from there. I want to harden my WordPress so I need to know how to block this.

I Googled the issue, but couldn't find any answers. Can someone provide info/links on how to block or remove this blog prefix in my domain/website name?

Comment: I guess you could redirect anything that starts with "blog"

Comment: why do you think that wordpress adds blog. as "prefix"? link?

Comment: though. blog here is a subdomain right?

Comment: never had that on my installs

Comment: That is clearly a subdomain, which is surely not done by WordPress if you're running the install as a single site, not multisite. In the last case, it could be WordPress, and you should check out the settings of your multisite install.

Otherwise I'd check in your hosting panel for any subdomains or aliasses wit 'blog.yoursite.pl'.

Comment: I made normal wordpress install in subfolder and evry wp instal make http://blog.mysite.pl. Its not like config from hosting - i used putty to install wp, I have looked whole hosting panel for any tips but didnt find anything

http://blog.pcdogier.pl/ pcdogier.pl - just instaled for test. I only used putty. Nothing more.